# How can I avoid errors when dividing by zero when using multiple lists

Tags: python, division

I have 2 lists with 4 values in each. These values will change every time the code is run.

```
probability = [4, 0.004e-2, 5.5, 0.0]
miss = [6954, 12507, 3621, 10440]
```

I have been plugging the lists into this formula which breaks when it sees a 0. What can I do to stop the errors (either replaced with a null or 0)?

```
severity = [a * 100 / b for a, b in zip(miss, probability)]
```

Comment: Your "lists" aren't valid Python.

Comment: sorry. made the edit

Comment: Why do you want to avoid errors? It's an error to divide by zero. Edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
severity = [0 if b==0 else a * 100 / b for a, b in zip(miss, probability)]
```

That is, use a conditional expression to avoid doing division when `b` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to test that values of `b` are never zero. If it is, either raise an exception, or assign `severity` some non-trivial value such as `None`, as you pointed out. You could do something like this:

```
severity = [None if b == 0 else a * 100 / b for a, b in zip(miss, probability)]
```

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. Yes, you are right. I edited the code.